# Problem with CORS..Angular and API Platform Symfony

Tags: angular, symfony, cors, api-platform.com

I have a big problem with CORS, I tested a lot of things but I can't fix the problem.

I use API Platform with nelmio cors, here is my configuration

```
nelmio_cors:
defaults:
    origin_regex: true
    allow_origin: ['%env(CORS_ALLOW_ORIGIN)%']
    allow_methods: ['GET', 'OPTIONS', 'POST', 'PUT', 'PATCH', 'DELETE']
    allow_headers: ['Content-Type', 'Authorization', 'X-LOCALE','Content-Language']
    expose_headers: ['Link']
    max_age: 3600
paths:
    '^/': null
```

CORS_ALLOW_ORIGIN I tested with *, .* and any posible pattern like http://localhost:[0-9]+
From the front, I use Angular I want to get a file store under backend/public/images/business-profile/file.png

I use a service

```
getFile(){
return this.httpClient.get('http://localhost:8000/images/business-profile/5f19ca78de1b5563889896.png')
}
```

And into the app component I use for get it

```
 this.testService.getFile().subscribe(
  (resp) => {
    this.file = resp;
  }
)
```

When I saw the browser I have this

[image]

Comment: Please share the error message in readable form, along with your debugging attempts

Answer (score 0):

Your indentation is not correct, defaults and paths is inside nelmio_cors

```yaml
nelmio_cors:
    defaults:
        origin_regex: true
        allow_origin: ['%env(CORS_ALLOW_ORIGIN)%']
        allow_methods: ['GET', 'OPTIONS', 'POST', 'PUT', 'PATCH', 'DELETE']
        allow_headers: ['Content-Type', 'Authorization', 'X-LOCALE','Content-Language']
        expose_headers: ['Link']
        max_age: 3600
    paths:
        '^/': null
```

Comment: How is it? Please  tell me

Comment: nelmio_cors is the root node of this bundle so all entires must be insed this node. Please refer to the doc: https://github.com/nelmio/NelmioCorsBundle#configuration

Comment: I would assume that this is a copy/paste error, as Symfony might throw an error for such unknown keys?

Comment: Yes in this case symfony should throw an exception

Comment: I tested for every params all posible combinations, I don't know why don't runs ok.